# Don't understand why: NameError: name 'numSyst' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x

Relatively new to python and cannot seem to trouble shoot why the program won't run past calling the function; I cannot seem to identify the name error. Please help

```
decimal = int(input("Enter decimal number to convert to base: "))
base = int(input("Enter base for the conversion: "))
print(" ____")
print(str(base)+"|"+str(decimal))
conversion = numSyst(decimal,base)
print("Base "+str(base)+" value of "+str(decimal)+" = "+conversion)
```

### Function Used in numSyst Function

```
def hex(remainder):
    hexN = ""
    if (remainder >=10 and remainder <=15):
        if remainder == 10:
            hexN = "A"
        if remainder == 11:
            hexN = "B"
        if remainder == 12:
            hexN = "C"
        if remainder == 13:
            hexN = "D"
        if remainder == 14:
            hexN = "E"
        if remainder == 15:
            hexN = "F"
    elif int(remainder) <= 9:
        hexN = str(remainder)

    return hexN
```

## Function used to do conversions - contains the NameError

```
def numSyst(decimal,base):
    num = ""
    remainder =-1
    if decimal == 0:
        num = "0";
    else:
        while decimal > 0:
            remainder = int(decimal%base)
            decimal = int(decimal//base)
            if base == 16:
                convert = int(remainder)
                num = num + hex(remainder)
            else:
                num = num + str(remainder)
    return num
```

Comment: What do you get in the output/Console Log?

Comment: Please check my answer below! You just need to define the functions in the right order

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are defining `hex`, then `numSyst`, then your code to call `numSyst` like so. In Python, the function you would like to use should be defined before you use it, in case of standalone script like here.

```
def hex(remainder):
    hexN = ""
    if (remainder >=10 and remainder <=15):
        if remainder == 10:
            hexN = "A"
        if remainder == 11:
            hexN = "B"
        if remainder == 12:
            hexN = "C"
        if remainder == 13:
            hexN = "D"
        if remainder == 14:
            hexN = "E"
        if remainder == 15:
            hexN = "F"
    elif int(remainder) <= 9:
        hexN = str(remainder)

    return hexN


def numSyst(decimal,base):
    num = ""
    remainder =-1
    if decimal == 0:
        num = "0"
    else:
        while decimal > 0:
            remainder = int(decimal%base)
            decimal = int(decimal//base)
            if base == 16:
                convert = int(remainder)
                num = num + hex(remainder)
            else:
                num = num + str(remainder)
    return num

decimal = int(input("Enter decimal number to convert to base: "))
base = int(input("Enter base for the conversion: "))
print(" ____")
print(str(base)+"|"+str(decimal))
conversion = numSyst(decimal,base)
print("Base "+str(base)+" value of "+str(decimal)+" = "+conversion)
#Enter decimal number to convert to base: 15
#Enter base for the conversion: 2
#____
#2|15
#Base 2 value of 15 = 1111
```